# How to add font awesome social icons?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I am looking to add font awesome flat social icons in my wordpress right sidebar.My theme has already font-awesome and font-awesome.min in CSS folder.I have no idea how to add it.

Comment: Please, be more specific and use the questions to solve specific codding errors / problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome_folder_name/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

into head.

Or directly add absolute link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Absolute links would be better than relative ones

Answer (score 0):

You place Font Awesome icons by using the prefix `fa` and the icon's name.

### Example

```
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
```

[**fontawesome.io**](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)  here you can find more icon.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the css link and use `<i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h1><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
<h2><i class="fa fa-wordpress" aria-hidden="true"></i><h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/font-awesome.css">
```

This is how you can call font awesome in your wordpress site. But firstly you have to keep font-awesome.min.css file in your css file.

Then You also need to copy the fonts of font-awesome file and paste it into your fonts folder.

Then you can use this icon by writting this-

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

In this code it will show a address book icon.

Go to font-awesome website to know others icon code.